# fetch the guild_id/member_id in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I try to remove a role using on_raw_rwaction_remove an remove_roles:

Because I don't have the `guild_id/member_id` in `on_raw_reaction_remove` I try to get it myself but got this error:

`Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request`

(and line 45 [`guild = await(bot.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id))`] causes the error)

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):

        ourMessageID = 867876893411508234

        if ourMessageID == payload.message_id:
            
            guild = await(bot.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id))
            print("fetch successful")
            

            if payload.emoji.name == 'YouTube':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="YouTube")
                print("Role checked")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'Twitch':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Twitch")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'Discord':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Discord")

            elif payload.emoji.name == 'alert':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Community-Events")

                member = await(guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id))
                print(member)
                if member is not None:
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                else:
                    print("Member not found")
```

(I get no response from the two print's)

If I could do something different/simpler, please let me know!

Comment: Have you ensured `payload.guild_id` is a valid `int`?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: error may suggest that `payload.guild_id` is `None`

Comment: try using get_member/get_guild and remove the await, and await is a keyword so it does not need parentheses

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me now, thanks for the help:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):

        ourMessageID = 867876893411508234

        if ourMessageID == payload.message_id:
            emoji = payload.emoji.name
            guild = await self.bot.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
            member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)

            #REST OF THE CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

The payload itslef doesn't have `guild id` but it does have the `channel_id`, `user_id` and `message_id` so you can use the `channel id` to fetch the `channel object` and then you can use `message id` to get the `message object` and get `guild_id` from it

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id) # returns channel object
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)# returns message object
    guild_id = message.guild.id #returns guild id

    #REST OF THE CODE
```